# document list and index of all files in all shared sites of sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have some ~30 shared sites (different sharing criteria for users) created in SharePoint where each site has a Documents folder where there are lots of files and sub-folders.

I want to know if there's a way for an index - to have each user list the documents of all sites' sub-folder and files at one place. They would need to be able to search as well, not just traverse through the entire tree.

I am open to writing code using the API to be hosted on our server, but is there a way to have it inside their SharePoint dashboard itself ?